# Runtime folder structure when running xUnit.net tests

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, xunit, xunit.net

I'm working on a C# web app running on .net 4.6.1 that assumes that certain dlls are in the same folder as the executing assembly and tries to import some types from those dlls using [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/). That works fine when the app is running and all the required dlls are in the bin folder, but I have problems when running xUnit tests that eventually get to run the code that makes the assumption mentioned above. I'm running the tests using Visual Studio 2017.

The problem I have is that when I run an xUnit test it creates a temp folder which contains a subfolder for each reference I have in my unit test project. In every subfolder there is the .dll and the .pdb file of a **single** reference along with an __AssemblyInfo__.ini file. Obviously, the test crashes with a FileNotFoundException because the code that wants to import some types using [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) cannot find the dlls in the same folder as the executing assembly location.

Is there a way to tell xUnit to put all the references of the unit test project in a single folder (like the bin folder?) and run the tests using that folder? Or is this maybe a setting in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply disable `shadowCopy`, so that all execution uses your output folder.

To learn how to configure xUnit.net via JSON, use a search engine.

Comment: This is only effective for the command line runner. I had to use the ReSharper options dialog box to disable shadow copying of assemblies being tested when running tests from within VS.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that's because you are using ReSharper. JetBrains decides to use its own settings and does not honor xUnit.net settings.

Comment: Yes, added the comment mainly for other visitors who come here like me and spend another 15 minutes googling and trying around until they find out why this answer doesn't help in their situation ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Clearly I answered just the question and ReSharper is not part of it. When you make a search, ask yourself what keywords should be used. I believe if you add ReSharper in your search keywords, JetBrains documentation should be at top to teach you what to do.

Comment: The OP wrote "I'm running the tests using Visual Studio 2017." I wasn't even aware the UI I was using to run tests belonged to ReSharper rather than VS itself until I happened to find out about the aforementioned ReSharper option. And even if I had been aware of that fact, the question doesn't say it's *not* valid for xUnit when run from ReSharper - who could guess ReSharper is an exception in that respect?

Comment: Note that I am not claiming your answer is wrong or incomplete (I actually upvoted it), just that there's a certain probability developers in the same situation as myself will stumble upon this answer and wonder why it apparently doesn't work for them.

Comment: "I wasn't even aware the UI I was using to run tests belonged to ReSharper rather than VS itself" is the actual problem you hit. Getting familiar with the development environment you use (such as how much of Visual Studio is changed by a huge tool like ReSharper) is always the key to address issues. Without such awareness, it will be a waste of time to search around.

Comment: And with such awareness, I would still have come here, because I would *not* have added the "ReSharper" search term, because it wouldn't have occurred to me that xUnit execution adheres to different settings when run in ReSharper. No matter how you look at it, there will be users who run xTest via ReSharper, find this question, wonder why the solution from your answer doesn't work for them, but then find the explanation in my comment. That's what made it the helpful, polite, and reasonable choice to add the information, which was the entire reason for me to add my comment.

Comment: @LexLi - the link provided in your answer is not available as of now. May I ask if you can update your answer with the latest link to xUnit Github documentation?